# Programmatically determine if an R function is pure

Tags: r

I'll paraphrase the definition of a pure function from a [Datacamp course](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/writing-functions-in-r) by [Hadley Wickham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley):

- Outputs depend only on inputs
- Don't change anything outside the function

  - No setting of global variables, no plotting, no printing to console, etc
- Don't have any inputs that can be different for different users or sessions

How can I determine if a particular function is pure in an automated fashion? I've thought about using `args()` to check for default values, but then I'm not sure how to check if the defaults are global values. And I've thought about checking which library a function comes from since some are known to contain mostly pure functions. But I don't think that's a test that works 100% of the time.

Any partial answers would also be helpful. For example: How can I determine if a function creates a plot? How can I determine if a function prints to the console? I imagine one could design test cases, but showing many positive results and not finding a negative one is also not definitive proof.

Comment: For the third one, can we assume that inputs that go in the function are themselves pure e.g, not generated by something that can differ per user, like getting an environmental variable?

Comment: I would prefer not to assume that the inputs can be different per user. It would be nice to have a way to check that as well.

Comment: `R CMD CHECK` does some of this - if you define a function that attempts to use an object not in the available namespace it will throw a warning, something like "no visible binding found for variable". You could look into the underlying code there.

Comment: On that note, does the definition of "pure" include a clause about packages (or is that assumed in the "inputs that can be different for different users)? I.e., are only `base` functions allowed?

Comment: @Gregor in the course, purrr was used as an example of a library that has many pure functions.

Comment: I think the definition of pure is more fundamental than saying that only base functions are allowed. And as a negative example, there are many base functions which are not pure, i.e. all plotting an printing functions.

Comment: What about error messages or warnings? Can they sully the purity of a function?

Comment: Yes they can. Errors and warnings should be captured as a part of the data (i.e. List) that a function returns.

Comment: *"more fundamental than saying that only base functions are allowed"*, yes, but allowable functions need to be considered. For an extreme example, `add1 = function(x) x + 1` seems like it would be "pure". `add1 = function(x) strangePackage::plus(x, 1)` seems like it would not be "pure" even if `strangePackage` defines `plus = function(a, b) a + b`. Unless I'm mistaken, `base::\`+\`` is allowable as a part of a "pure" function, but functions from `strangePackage` are not. The question is where you draw the line. It would be a necessary but not sufficient condition for purity.

Comment: Or is it recursive? Pure functions can only include other pure functions, regardless of where they are defined?

Comment: I think the recursive idea could be sufficient but there are examples where pure functions are created out of non pure functions. Maybe trivial, but a function that captures errors and stores them in the output rather than allowing them to be printed to the screen (or interrupt execution) could turn a non-pure function into a pure one.

Answer (score -2):

Fun question.  To answer many of these problems you're going to have to play around with environments.  Read [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

Here is a simple solution to your first question.  The problem can be defined as follows.

```
y <- 1

f <- function(x){
  x + y
}

f(10)
[1] 11
```

This happens because of R's scoping rules.  When you call `f()` R looks within the function's call frame (local environment), if it can't find what it wants, it moves up to the parent environment, which in this case is the workspace (i.e. `.GlobalEnv`).  So an easy answer is to move `.GlobalEnv` to a different environment not on the `f()`'s search path, and then call `f()`.  For example,

```
y <- 1

e <- new.env() #intitalizing a new environment 

#populating e with objects in `.GlobalEnv`
for(i in ls()[!grepl("e",ls())]){
  assign(i, globalenv()[[i]], envir = e)
}

rm(list = ls()[!grepl("e",ls())]) #removing everything from the global environment that is not our environment e

f <- function(x){
  x + y
}

f(10)

Error in f(10) : object 'y' not found
```

Now let's move the objects previously within the global environment back

```
for(i in ls(envir = e)){
   assign(i, e[[i]])
}
```

There maybe a much better way to do the above, however, it is a start.  I'm also certain that the answer to many of your questions will be obtained by playing around with the idea of environments. For example your second question regarding global variables could be answered by comparing the global environment before and after a function call.  Or by passing the call frame to the global enviroment for inspection.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful example for enviornments.